# Why don't I have a loop error with these redirects?

Tags: web-development, htaccess, redirects, webserver

I know this may seem a bit of a question in reverse, but I actually *don't* seem to have a problem I just want to make sure before I proceed.

I have 2 domains `domain1.com` and `domain2.com` and a directory `my_directory` at `domain2.com`.

I have `domain2.com` setup as an "add on domain" in the cpanel account of domain1.com so that when I go to domain2.com I am taken to domain1.com/my_directory but the browser shows domain2.com in the addressbar so it looks and acts like and is a separate site.

However when people browse to `domain1.com/directory` I want the address bar to show `domain2.com` *not* `domain1.com/directory`. So I put a redirect in the htaccess file to redirect `domain1.com/directory` to `domain2.com` and it works perfectly, but I think it shouldnt and I'm worried I've done something wrong.

My question is this: domain2.com was already redirected to domain1.com/directory in the first place (I see the redirect in my cpanel under addon domains) so by adding the second redirect in the htaccess file I should be creating a loop!

Could somebody please set my mind at rest and show me why not?

Comment: nice edit jeff you make it seem so easy !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 2 different mechanisms.

You have a **redirect** so that when someone visits domain1.com/my_directory they are redirected to domain2.com.

You have a **rewrite** so that when someone visits domain2.com they actually see the content from domain1.com/my_directory. This is processed internally within apache. It is not processing the redirect rule.

Comment: thanks - that would make sense but cpanel calls it (under addon domain)  a redirect not a rewrite could this be a bit erroneous that would explain it